# CSS float doesn't position <div>s correctly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, formatting, css-float

I am having a problem with CSS. I have `<div>` element with two `<div>`s inside. One of them has the style `float:left`, the other one has `float:right`. Their width is set to 50% and it all works great, they are aligned exactly the way they should. The problem is when I set @media min-width:500px, I want them to behave normally as `<div>`s and to display one below other. This happens, but second div is not aligned to left as it should, instead it stays to right, and just goes below the first div.

How do I fix this?

Comment: do you have some code or possibly a jsbin and screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/jopoxo/1/edit?html,css,output)***

Inside your `@media` set **width to `100%`** (or `auto`).
If you want, as a *plus* you can also **reset** your **floats** to `none`

```
@media (max-width: 768px)  {
     .left, .right{
           float:none;
           width:100%; /* or `auto` */
      }
}
```

Comment: The thing that confuses me is that it works without clearing the floats, only with setting width to 100%.

Comment: @NikolaPalibrk well, obviously the `float:none;` is not a *must-have* - since if you stretch your elements to 100% - there's no space left for another element to float aside. `float:none;` helps cause floated elements cause inconsintencies among it's parent elements (containing floated child elements), to avoid headaches later doing complicated stuff with @media... *why not, let's use it*!